# Can GCM be used as a two way communication?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, server

Can GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) be used as a two way communication between the device and the server?

Please Help with the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can. That's what [GCM CCS](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) (Cloud Connection Server) is all about. It enables you to use GCM both both cloud to device and device to cloud messaging. The older version of GCM (the HTTP version) only supports messages from the server to the device (cloud to device).

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Can you tell the appropriate link to set it up with google app Engine. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use XMPP and HTTP to complete what you are looking for.  GCM offers both services.  You can find a great starter tut here http://www.grokkingandroid.com/xmpp-server-google-cloud-messaging/

The google documentation isn't bad either.  https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

The Smack API is what you will use to get XMPP working on the server side.  You can find that here http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/

We also use Retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/ which is great for handing off objects via http.

Good luck, be sure to ask questions, figuring it all out in the beginning is a bit painful but worth it in the end.  Also checkout RabitMQ http://www.rabbitmq.com/, it's similar to GCM